# Creating dynamic web forms in ASP.NET

Tags: dynamic, reflection, webforms, system.reflection

My project aims to provide the end user the ability to dynamically design forms in run-time. That would be something like a simple web based IDE to design web-forms.

The end user should be able enter all the components and their respective properties of the web form at runtime.

A web form should be generated based on the components and properties defined by the user and the final form should be displayed.

Is reflections the best ways to do this? If so could you please point me an appropriate page as to how I would have to do this?

Are there other ways to implement this apart from reflections?

I tried researching on web-parts but , I came to realize that web parts was not what I intended to do with the project because I would not know any of the properties of the components in advance during compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be webforms and its controls running from server ( from System.Web.UI )?

Just to share some experience, we have a huuge codegeneration like applications, which given parameters ( which could be input like ones or the whole database depending of the case )  can generate html submiting forms to server side using jquery and/or dojo ajax features...

because we want simplicity, we decided we would not generate server side controls dinamicaly

the bottom line is, I don't know your requirement, but maybe you want to do something similar.

Comment: Yes, it would have to be a webform with controls running from the server. The end user would be given a form to choose the component to add to the dynamic form also enter all the properties of the specific component. This would be saved to database. Finally a webform should be generated based on properties of all the components stored on a database for that specific dynamic form.